# Is there a list of all connected T_0-spaces with 5 points?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, online-resources

Is there some place (on the internet or elsewhere) where I can find the number and preferably a list of all (isomorphism classes of) finite connected $T_0$-spaces with, say, 5 points?

In know that a $T_0$-topology on a finite set is equivalent to a partial ordering, and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order) tells me that there are, up to isomorphism, 63 partially ordered sets with precisely 5 elements. However, I am only interested in connected spaces, and I'd love to have a list (most preferably in terms of Hasse diagrams).

Comment: I also asked this at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/is-there-a-list-of-all-connected-t-0-spaces-with-5-points but did not receive much response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Java applet that displays all 5-element connected posets at 
http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/gap/posets.html.

Comment: I don't get it to work. Do you also see just one yellow thing if you try, and don't know what to do with that?

Comment: It worked o.k. for me. I got the Hasse diagrams of all connected 5-element posets by clicking on "All connected Posets with 5 elements". 

Comment: For those who have the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9279/problems-with-java-applet

Answer (score 11):

Peter Jipsen has granted me permission to post static images of his posets.

4-element connected posets (10):

[image: all 4-element connected posets by Peter Jipson]

5-element connected posets (44):

[image: all 5-element connected posets by Peter Jipson]

Since the number (139) of distinct 5-element topological spaces (up to homeomorphism) is manageably small
and there don't seem to be any lists posted anywhere, I am posting one here.  The first (second) row lists smallest closed (open) supersets of singletons and the rows that follow list all nontrivial open sets.

**1** T_0

```
    a b c d e
    -----
    a b c d e
    -----
    a b c d e
    ab ac ad ae bc bd be cd ce de
    abc abd abe acd ace ade bcd bce bde cde
    abcd abce abde acde bcde
```

**2** T_0

```
    ae b c d e
    -----
    a b c d ae
    -----
    a b c d
    ab ac ad ae bc bd cd
    abc abd abe acd ace ade bcd
    abcd abce abde acde
```

**3** T_0

```
    ae be c d e
    -----
    a b c d abe
    -----
    a b c d
    ab ac ad bc bd cd
    abc abd abe acd bcd
    abcd abce abde
```

**4** T_0

```
    ae be ce d e
    -----
    a b c d abce
    -----
    a b c d
    ab ac ad bc bd cd
    abc abd acd bcd
    abcd abce
```

**5** connected T_0, poset (4,2)

```
    ae be ce de e
    -----
    a b c d abcde
    -----
    a b c d
    ab ac ad bc bd cd
    abc abd acd bcd
    abcd
```

**6** T_0

```
    ade b c d e
    -----
    a b c ad ae
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad ae bc
    abc abd abe acd ace ade
    abcd abce abde acde
```

**7** T_0

```
    ad be c d e
    -----
    a b c ad be
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc be
    abc abd abe acd bce
    abcd abce abde
```

**8** T_0

```
    ade be c d e
    -----
    a b c ad abe
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc
    abc abd abe acd
    abcd abce abde
```

**9** T_0

```
    ade b c de e
    -----
    a b c ad ade
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc
    abc abd acd ade
    abcd abde acde
```

**10**

```
    a b c de de
    -----
    a b c de de
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc de
    abc ade bde cde
    abde acde bcde
```

**11** T_0

```
    ad be ce d e
    -----
    a b c ad bce
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc
    abc abd acd bce
    abcd abce
```

**12** connected T_0, poset (1,9)

```
    ade be ce d e
    -----
    a b c ad abce
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc
    abc abd acd
    abcd abce
```

**13** T_0

```
    ade be c de e
    -----
    a b c ad abde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc
    abc abd acd
    abcd abde
```

**14** connected T_0, poset (4,3)

```
    ade be ce de e
    -----
    a b c ad abcde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac ad bc
    abc abd acd
    abcd
```

**15** T_0

```
    ade bde c d e
    -----
    a b c abd abe
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**16** connected T_0, poset (2,6)

```
    ade bd ce d e
    -----
    a b c abd ace
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc abd ace
    abcd abce
```

**17** connected T_0, poset (2,9)

```
    ade bde ce d e
    -----
    a b c abd abce
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**18** T_0

```
    ade bde c de e
    -----
    a b c abd abde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc abd
    abcd abde
```

**19**

```
    ade b c de de
    -----
    a b c ade ade
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc ade
    abde acde
```

**20** connected T_0, poset (4,6)

```
    ade bde ce de e
    -----
    a b c abd abcde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**21** connected T_0, poset (3,6)

```
    ade bde cde d e
    -----
    a b c abcd abce
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**22** connected T_0, poset (5,4)

```
    ade bde cde de e
    -----
    a b c abcd abcde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc
    abcd
```

**23**

```
    ade bde c de de
    -----
    a b c abde abde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc
    abde
```

**24** connected

```
    ade bde cde de de
    -----
    a b c abcde abcde
    -----
    a b c
    ab ac bc
    abc
```

**25** T_0

```
    acde b c d e
    -----
    a b ac ad ae
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad ae
    abc abd abe acd ace ade
    abcd abce abde acde
```

**26** T_0

```
    acd be c d e
    -----
    a b ac ad be
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad be
    abc abd abe acd
    abcd abce abde
```

**27** connected T_0, poset (1,2)

```
    acde be c d e
    -----
    a b ac ad abe
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad
    abc abd abe acd
    abcd abce abde
```

**28** T_0

```
    acde b ce d e
    -----
    a b ac ad ace
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad
    abc abd acd ace
    abcd abce acde
```

**29** connected T_0, poset (1,4)

```
    ace bde c d e
    -----
    a b ac bd abe
    -----
    a b
    ab ac bd
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**30** connected T_0, poset (2,1)

```
    acde be ce d e
    -----
    a b ac ad abce
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad
    abc abd acd
    abcd abce
```

**31** T_0

```
    acde b ce de e
    -----
    a b ac ad acde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad
    abc abd acd
    abcd acde
```

**32** T_0

```
    ace bd ce d e
    -----
    a b ac bd ace
    -----
    a b
    ab ac bd
    abc abd ace
    abcd abce
```

**33**

```
    ac b c de de
    -----
    a b ac de de
    -----
    a b
    ab ac de
    abc ade bde
    abde acde
```

**34** connected T_0, poset (4,4)

```
    acde be ce de e
    -----
    a b ac ad abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac ad
    abc abd acd
    abcd
```

**35** connected T_0, poset (2,3)

```
    ace bde ce d e
    -----
    a b ac bd abce
    -----
    a b
    ab ac bd
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**36** connected T_0, poset (4,8)

```
    ace bde ce de e
    -----
    a b ac bd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac bd
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**37** connected T_0, poset (1,5)

```
    acde bde c d e
    -----
    a b ac abd abe
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**38** T_0

```
    acde b cde d e
    -----
    a b ac acd ace
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc acd ace
    abcd abce acde
```

**39**

```
    a b cde cde e
    -----
    a b cd cd cde
    -----
    a b
    ab cd
    acd bcd cde
    abcd acde bcde
```

**40** connected T_0, poset (2,7)

```
    acde bd ce d e
    -----
    a b ac abd ace
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc abd ace
    abcd abce
```

**41**

```
    ac bc c de de
    -----
    a b abc de de
    -----
    a b
    ab de
    abc ade bde
    abde
```

**42** connected T_0, poset (3,2)

```
    acde bde ce d e
    -----
    a b ac abd abce
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**43** connected T_0, poset (2,4)

```
    acde bde c de e
    -----
    a b ac abd abde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc abd
    abcd abde
```

**44** connected T_0, poset (3,1)

```
    acde be cde d e
    -----
    a b ac acd abce
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc acd
    abcd abce
```

**45** T_0

```
    acde b cde de e
    -----
    a b ac acd acde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc acd
    abcd acde
```

**46**

```
    acde b c de de
    -----
    a b ac ade ade
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc ade
    abde acde
```

**47**

```
    ae b cde cde e
    -----
    a b cd cd acde
    -----
    a b
    ab cd
    acd bcd
    abcd acde
```

**48** connected T_0, poset (4,7)

```
    acde bde ce de e
    -----
    a b ac abd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**49** connected T_0, poset (4,9)

```
    acde be cde de e
    -----
    a b ac acd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc acd
    abcd
```

**50**

```
    ac bde c de de
    -----
    a b ac bde bde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc bde
    abde
```

**51** connected

```
    ae be cde cde e
    -----
    a b cd cd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab cd
    acd bcd
    abcd
```

**52** connected T_0, poset (3,7)

```
    acde bde cde d e
    -----
    a b ac abcd abce
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**53** connected T_0, poset (5,5)

```
    acde bde cde de e
    -----
    a b ac abcd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc
    abcd
```

**54** connected

```
    acde bde c de de
    -----
    a b ac abde abde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc
    abde
```

**55**

```
    acde b cde de de
    -----
    a b ac acde acde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc
    acde
```

**56** connected

```
    acde bde cde de de
    -----
    a b ac abcde abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab ac
    abc
```

**57** connected T_0, poset (1,7)

```
    acde bcde c d e
    -----
    a b abc abd abe
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**58** connected T_0, poset (3,4)

```
    acde bcde ce d e
    -----
    a b abc abd abce
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**59** connected T_0, poset (5,2)

```
    acde bcde ce de e
    -----
    a b abc abd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**60** connected

```
    acde bc c de de
    -----
    a b abc ade ade
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc ade
    abde
```

**61** connected T_0, poset (3,9)

```
    acde bcde cde d e
    -----
    a b abc abcd abce
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**62**

```
    acde b cde cde e
    -----
    a b acd acd acde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    acd
    abcd acde
```

**63**

```
    a b cde cde cde
    -----
    a b cde cde cde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    cde
    acde bcde
```

**64** connected T_0, poset (5,7)

```
    acde bcde cde de e
    -----
    a b abc abcd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc
    abcd
```

**65** connected

```
    acde bcde c de de
    -----
    a b abc abde abde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc
    abde
```

**66** connected

```
    acde be cde cde e
    -----
    a b acd acd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    acd
    abcd
```

**67** connected

```
    acde bcde cde de de
    -----
    a b abc abcde abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abc
```

**68** connected

```
    acde bcde cde cde e
    -----
    a b abcd abcd abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    abcd
```

**69**

```
    acde b cde cde cde
    -----
    a b acde acde acde
    -----
    a b
    ab
    acde
```

**70** connected

```
    acde bcde cde cde cde
    -----
    a b abcde abcde abcde
    -----
    a b
    ab
```

**71** connected T_0, poset (1,1)

```
    abcde b c d e
    -----
    a ab ac ad ae
    -----
    a
    ab ac ad ae
    abc abd abe acd ace ade
    abcd abce abde acde
```

**72** connected T_0, poset (1,3)

```
    abcde be c d e
    -----
    a ab ac ad abe
    -----
    a
    ab ac ad
    abc abd abe acd
    abcd abce abde
```

**73** connected T_0, poset (2,2)

```
    abcde be ce d e
    -----
    a ab ac ad abce
    -----
    a
    ab ac ad
    abc abd acd
    abcd abce
```

**74** connected T_0, poset (4,5)

```
    abcde be ce de e
    -----
    a ab ac ad abcde
    -----
    a
    ab ac ad
    abc abd acd
    abcd
```

**75**

```
    abc b c de de
    -----
    a ab ac de de
    -----
    a
    ab ac de
    abc ade
    abde acde
```

**76** connected T_0, poset (1,6)

```
    abcde bde c d e
    -----
    a ab ac abd abe
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**77** connected T_0, poset (2,8)

```
    abcde bd ce d e
    -----
    a ab ac abd ace
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc abd ace
    abcd abce
```

**78** connected T_0, poset (3,3)

```
    abcde bde ce d e
    -----
    a ab ac abd abce
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**79** connected T_0, poset (2,5)

```
    abcde bde c de e
    -----
    a ab ac abd abde
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc abd
    abcd abde
```

**80** connected

```
    abcde b c de de
    -----
    a ab ac ade ade
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc ade
    abde acde
```

**81**

```
    ab b cde cde e
    -----
    a ab cd cd cde
    -----
    a
    ab cd
    acd cde
    abcd acde
```

**82** connected T_0, poset (5,1)

```
    abcde bde ce de e
    -----
    a ab ac abd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**83**

```
    abc bc c de de
    -----
    a ab abc de de
    -----
    a
    ab de
    abc ade
    abde
```

**84**

```
    a bc bc de de
    -----
    a bc bc de de
    -----
    a
    bc de
    abc ade
    bcde
```

**85** connected T_0, poset (3,8)

```
    abcde bde cde d e
    -----
    a ab ac abcd abce
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**86** connected

```
    abe b cde cde e
    -----
    a ab cd cd acde
    -----
    a
    ab cd
    acd
    abcd acde
```

**87** connected T_0, poset (5,6)

```
    abcde bde cde de e
    -----
    a ab ac abcd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc
    abcd
```

**88** connected

```
    abcde bde c de de
    -----
    a ab ac abde abde
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc
    abde
```

**89** connected

```
    abe be cde cde e
    -----
    a ab cd cd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab cd
    acd
    abcd
```

**90** connected

```
    abcde bde cde de de
    -----
    a ab ac abcde abcde
    -----
    a
    ab ac
    abc
```

**91** connected T_0, poset (1,8)

```
    abcde bcde c d e
    -----
    a ab abc abd abe
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**92**

```
    a bcde bcde d e
    -----
    a bc bc bcd bce
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc bcd bce
    abcd abce bcde
```

**93** connected T_0, poset (3,5)

```
    abcde bcde ce d e
    -----
    a ab abc abd abce
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**94** connected

```
    ae bcde bcde d e
    -----
    a bc bc bcd abce
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc bcd
    abcd abce
```

**95**

```
    a bcde bcde de e
    -----
    a bc bc bcd bcde
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc bcd
    abcd bcde
```

**96** connected T_0, poset (5,3)

```
    abcde bcde ce de e
    -----
    a ab abc abd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**97** connected

```
    abcde bc c de de
    -----
    a ab abc ade ade
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc ade
    abde
```

**98** connected

```
    ae bcde bcde de e
    -----
    a bc bc bcd abcde
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc bcd
    abcd
```

**99**

```
    ade bc bc de de
    -----
    a bc bc ade ade
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc ade
```

**100** connected T_0, poset (4,1)

```
    abcde bcde cde d e
    -----
    a ab abc abcd abce
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**101** connected

```
    abcde b cde cde e
    -----
    a ab acd acd acde
    -----
    a
    ab
    acd
    abcd acde
```

**102** connected

```
    ade bcde bcde d e
    -----
    a bc bc abcd abce
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**103** connected T_0, poset (5,8)

```
    abcde bcde cde de e
    -----
    a ab abc abcd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc
    abcd
```

**104** connected

```
    abcde bcde c de de
    -----
    a ab abc abde abde
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc
    abde
```

**105** connected

```
    abcde be cde cde e
    -----
    a ab acd acd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab
    acd
    abcd
```

**106**

```
    ab b cde cde cde
    -----
    a ab cde cde cde
    -----
    a
    ab
    cde
    acde
```

**107** connected

```
    ade bcde bcde de e
    -----
    a bc bc abcd abcde
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc
    abcd
```

**108**

```
    a bcde bcde de de
    -----
    a bc bc bcde bcde
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc
    bcde
```

**109** connected

```
    abcde bcde cde de de
    -----
    a ab abc abcde abcde
    -----
    a
    ab
    abc
```

**110** connected

```
    ade bcde bcde de de
    -----
    a bc bc abcde abcde
    -----
    a
    bc
    abc
```

**111** connected

```
    abcde bcde cde cde e
    -----
    a ab abcd abcd abcde
    -----
    a
    ab
    abcd
```

**112** connected

```
    abcde b cde cde cde
    -----
    a ab acde acde acde
    -----
    a
    ab
    acde
```

**113** connected

```
    abcde bcde cde cde cde
    -----
    a ab abcde abcde abcde
    -----
    a
    ab
```

**114** connected

```
    abcde bc bc de de
    -----
    a abc abc ade ade
    -----
    a
    abc ade
```

**115** connected

```
    abcde bcde bcde d e
    -----
    a abc abc abcd abce
    -----
    a
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**116**

```
    a bcde bcde bcde e
    -----
    a bcd bcd bcd bcde
    -----
    a
    bcd
    abcd bcde
```

**117** connected

```
    abcde bcde bcde de e
    -----
    a abc abc abcd abcde
    -----
    a
    abc
    abcd
```

**118** connected

```
    ae bcde bcde bcde e
    -----
    a bcd bcd bcd abcde
    -----
    a
    bcd
    abcd
```

**119** connected

```
    abcde bcde bcde de de
    -----
    a abc abc abcde abcde
    -----
    a
    abc
```

**120** connected

```
    abcde bcde bcde bcde e
    -----
    a abcd abcd abcd abcde
    -----
    a
    abcd
```

**121**

```
    a bcde bcde bcde bcde
    -----
    a bcde bcde bcde bcde
    -----
    a
    bcde
```

**122** connected

```
    abcde bcde bcde bcde bcde
    -----
    a abcde abcde abcde abcde
    -----
    a
```

**123**

```
    abc abc c de de
    -----
    ab ab abc de de
    -----
    ab de
    abc
    abde
```

**124** connected

```
    abe abe cde cde e
    -----
    ab ab cd cd abcde
    -----
    ab cd
    abcd
```

**125** connected

```
    abcde abcde c d e
    -----
    ab ab abc abd abe
    -----
    ab
    abc abd abe
    abcd abce abde
```

**126** connected

```
    abcde abcde ce d e
    -----
    ab ab abc abd abce
    -----
    ab
    abc abd
    abcd abce
```

**127** connected

```
    abcde abcde ce de e
    -----
    ab ab abc abd abcde
    -----
    ab
    abc abd
    abcd
```

**128** connected

```
    abcde abcde cde d e
    -----
    ab ab abc abcd abce
    -----
    ab
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**129** connected

```
    abcde abcde cde de e
    -----
    ab ab abc abcd abcde
    -----
    ab
    abc
    abcd
```

**130** connected

```
    abcde abcde c de de
    -----
    ab ab abc abde abde
    -----
    ab
    abc
    abde
```

**131** connected

```
    abcde abcde cde de de
    -----
    ab ab abc abcde abcde
    -----
    ab
    abc
```

**132**

```
    ab ab cde cde cde
    -----
    ab ab cde cde cde
    -----
    ab
    cde
```

**133** connected

```
    abcde abcde cde cde e
    -----
    ab ab abcd abcd abcde
    -----
    ab
    abcd
```

**134** connected

```
    abcde abcde cde cde cde
    -----
    ab ab abcde abcde abcde
    -----
    ab
```

**135** connected

```
    abcde abcde abcde d e
    -----
    abc abc abc abcd abce
    -----
    abc
    abcd abce
```

**136** connected

```
    abcde abcde abcde de e
    -----
    abc abc abc abcd abcde
    -----
    abc
    abcd
```

**137** connected

```
    abcde abcde abcde de de
    -----
    abc abc abc abcde abcde
    -----
    abc
```

**138** connected

```
    abcde abcde abcde abcde e
    -----
    abcd abcd abcd abcd abcde
    -----
    abcd
```

**139** connected

```
    abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
    -----
    abcde abcde abcde abcde abcde
    -----
    trivial topology
```

Comment: I happened to see this just now. You might be interested in the article I cited in my answer to [Finite Hausdorff topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2504314/finite-hausdorff-topological-spaces). The reference I gave also gives the number of connected $T_0$ spaces and connected $T_1$ spaces, and from what I can recall, those numbers don't differ all that much (percentage wise) from the "not necessarily connected" numbers I posted.

Answer (score 4):

At the [online encyclopedia of integer sequences](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html) we find, when we type T_0 topologies several hits. Sequence A028856 is the sequence of homeomorphism classes of T_0 topologies, and A028858 has all connected ones (308 topologies of which 235 connected, on 5 points).
No explicit list of spaces, though, but some literature references that might help.

Comment: I think the number 235 refers to 6-point spaces, doesn't it? For the second number in the sequence, 3, should refer to 3-point spaces (on a set with two elements there is only one connected T_0 topology. 

Comment: So, the number I asked for is 44, I guess.